# right inverse of surjective linear map on hilbert space exists iff kernel is complement subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Suppose that $L : H \to H'$ is a surjective continuous linear transformation between Hilbert spaces. Show that there exists a continuous linear transformation $S : H' \to H$ such that $LS = I$. Furthermore, show that we can ensure that the range of $S$ is orthogonal to the kernel of $L$, and that this condition determines $S$ uniquely.

What I tried to do is to make orthogonal complement of $ker (L)$(it is closed since $L$ is linear), say $K$, then define $S : H' \to H$ by $x' \mapsto k$ where $k \in K$ such that $L(k) = x'$. (This is well-defined since for any $x' \in H'$, there is $y \in X$ such that $L(y)$, and since $y = k+n$ where $k \in K$, $n \in ker(L)$, $L(y) = L(k+n) = L(k)+L(n)=L(k)+0=x'$, and $k$ is unique.) What I have trouble is the proof of $Im(S)=K$. By definition, $Im(S) \subseteq K$. But I don't know how to show $K \subseteq Im(S)$. Could you suggest some idea? If possible, please verify my proof to check whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: You forgot to prove the continuity of $S$, which is not trivial, you may need the open mapping theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems perfect.

(Well, a small thing: $\ker(L)$ is closed since $L$ is *continuous* linear..)

If $x\in K\subseteq H$, then let $y:=L(x)\,\in H'$, then by definition we have $S(y)=x$.

The last part (that $S$ is determined uniquely by the mentioned properties) is still to be proved.

Comment: Wow! Actually it's simple. Thank you! I think uniqueness of S is easy. Make $S':H' \to H$ as $x \mapsto k+n$ for some $n \in ker(L)$. Then it is still linear, continuous( with $\epsilon-\delta$ argument), but its image is not complement to $ker(L)$.